# Why there is no response after I clicked in a JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have the following sample Java Swing `JTable` app:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class JTableListSelectionListener
{
  public static void main(String[] a)
  {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JTable table;

    String[] columnTitles={"A","B","C","D"};
    Object[][] rowData={{"11","12","13","14"},{"21","22","23","24"},{"31","32","33","34"},{"41","42","43","44"}};

    table=new JTable(rowData,columnTitles);

    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    ListSelectionModel cellSelectionModel=table.getSelectionModel();
    cellSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
    {
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
      {
        String selectedData=null;

        int[] selectedRow=table.getSelectedRows();
        int[] selectedColumns=table.getSelectedColumns();

        for (int i=0;i<selectedRow.length;i++)
          for (int j=0;j<selectedColumns.length;j++)
            selectedData=(String)table.getValueAt(selectedRow[i],selectedColumns[j]);
        System.out.println("Selected: "+selectedData);
      }

    });

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(300,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

It won't respond if I click on the same row: 
If I click on "12" then on "13" or first click on "21" then click on "23", why?

1. How to fix it so no matter where I click in whichever order, it will always output the value in that cell?
2. How to be able to tell if I have clicked with the left mouse button or the right mouse button?

Comment: _"It won't respond if I click on the same row : 12 -> 13 or 21 -> 23"_ -- this is unclear. What is "same row"?

Comment: More details added.

Comment: A `JTable` is not a spreadsheet.  You can code a `JTable` so it acts like a spreadsheet, but it requires a lot of custom code.  too much custom code for a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the `ListSelectionModel` for the `JTable` managers the row selection only, from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel())

> Returns the ListSelectionModel that is used to maintain row selection state.

This means that of the row selection doesn't change, you won't get a notification.

Instead, you probably want to use the `ListSelectionModel` used by the `TableColumnModel`, for example...

```
table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Selected column");
    }
});
```

Comment: But then with "table.getColumnModel()", if I click on 11 and then click on 31 [ same column ], it won't respond ? And if you add "table.getColumnModel()" to/after the existing code, then it would respond to both row and col change, so if I first click on "12" then click on "33", it would output "33" twice [ 1st one from row change, 2nd one from col change ?

Comment: @Frank Please take the time to read through [How to Write a List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to get a better understanding of how `ListSelectionListener`s work and why you're getting two events

Comment: thanks for the comment, I've looked at it and also the TableListSelectionDemo, I wonder if there is a solution for my problem : how to output the value in the cell [ only once ] every time I click on any cell be it the same row or same col as the last clicked cell ?